# How to use the blue top menu in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: editing-menu

While searching for Sharepoint 2013 branding I often see that the (blue) top menu is used. 
Example:
[image]

In my local test environment there is only one entry named "SharePoint" and nothing else.

How can I use this menu? Is there any possibility to use it for site-collections or web-applications or is it just for other Microsoft tools like office 365 and SkyDrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you asked about suite links bar. How to modify it you can read [here](http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/11/04/adding-your-own-links-to-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/).

Comment: what if your site doesn't even HAVE the suite links to start with?